# R Optimization over Dataframe

Tags: r, optimization

I have the following code where I want to find the beste Values for x,y and z.

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(3,sample(0:100,100,rep=TRUE)))

find_best <- function(xyz) {
  x <- xyz[1]
  y <- xyz[2]
  z <- xyz[3]
  nr <- count(df)
  val <- count(df[df[, "X1"] < x & df[, "X2"] < y & df[, "X3"] < z, ] )
  return(val$n/nr$n)
}

optim(par = c(30,15,15), fn = find_best,  lower=c(0,0,0), upper=c(100,100,100), method="L-BFGS-B")
```

The function does not achieve much at the moment, but I will add constraints later. However if I run this, I only get the value of the initial values back.

```
$par
[1] 30 15 15
```

So the question is, how can I get the best values for x,y,z either with optim or with anything else.

Comment: what is `count()` in your function `find_best()`?

Comment: it's just the rowcount.
Currently I return how many rows satisfy the condition divided by the total number of rows

Comment: what do you mean by `best values for x, y and z`?  to maximize `val/nr`?

Comment: yeah, currently it is pretty useless, because it would just yield the max values, but as I said, i will add more constraints later, as soon as the optimizing algorithm is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you  can use `optim` for your purpose

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(replicate(3,sample(0:100,1e5,rep=TRUE)))

find_best <- function(xyz) {
  x <- xyz[1]
  y <- xyz[2]
  z <- xyz[3]
  r <- nrow(subset(df,X1 < x & X2 < y & X3 < z))/nrow(df)
}

res <- optim(par = c(35,15,15), fn = find_best,  lower=c(0,0,0), upper=c(100,100,100), control = list(fnscale = -1))
```

which gives

```
> res
$par
[1] 35.085 15.205 15.225

$value
[1] 0.00881

$counts
function gradient 
       2        2 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: NORM OF PROJECTED GRADIENT <= PGTOL"
```

Comment: thanks a lot. But why doesn't your function have a return value?

Comment: @HansGeber sorry that I forgot to paste `res <- ` in my code...see my update

Comment: it seems that I can't use borders, when I use your method

Comment: what do you mean `use boarders`?

Comment: an upper and lower bound

Comment: @HansGeber I guess it depends on your objective function `find_best`, since you are not able to provide gradient function according to your request, the `optim` will give you optimized values around the given initial values